# FFMPEG: Can I store a specific color component in a separate video stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to store video with alpha channel, but most video encodings (like H.264, MPEG2) do not support alpha channel. As most muxer formats support multiple streams, I'm wondering if I could encode YUV components in a video stream, and alpha component in a second stream?

Note: though there are some video encodings that support alpha channel (such as VP9), I still want to try this approach as a last resort.

Comment: You may try using [extractplanes](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/extractplanes.htm.gz) filter "chained" with [mergeplanes](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/mergeplanes.htm.gz) filter.

Comment: You can use extractplanes to generate and store the alpha as a separate stream, but you will have to manually apply it as a matte in your consuming app.